# Is it possible for a value of a function to have two derivatives and if not, then why?

Tags: calculus

Take for a simple example $y=|x|$.

Say you need to find the derivate at $x=0$. If you approach from opposite sides of the $x$ axis, on one side the derivative is $1$ and from the other side the derivative is $-1$. It seems to me that you can't have conflicting derivatives but is there a proof for why this is? Also is there continuity as both the lines of opposite gradient meet at the same coordinate, $(0,0)$?

Comment: See [signum function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_function)

Comment: I think you just simply say that the function does not have a derivative when it has multiple derivatives when approached from different sides

Comment: $y=|x|$ is not differentiable at $x=0$. There is a proof that shows that if the function has a derivative at a point, then it is unique

Comment: Remember the definition of derivative is in terms of limits.  $\frac{d}{dx}[f(x)]=\lim\limits_{h\to 0}\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$.  Although the right-sided limit and the left-sided limit exist for $x=0$ *the actual limit itself doesn't exist* since they don't agree.  Derivatives aren't "right-limits" and "left-limits"... derivatives are *limits*.

Comment: "Also is there continuity"... continuity of what?  Of the derivative?  Well.. we just talked about how the derivative in this case isn't a function., but we could call it a "partial function" (*or making it a function by restricting its domain to $\Bbb R\setminus\{0\}$, i.e. removing zero from the domain*).  In that case, no it wouldn't be continuous, again because of what happens as you approach $0$ from different directions.  As for the continuity of the original function, yes it is continuous.

Comment: continuity of the function y=|x|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, we can't have conflicting derivatives. We say that a function $f$ is $\textit{differentiable at $x_0$}$ if these limits from different directions agree, therefore $|x|$ is not differentiable at $x=0$.  As for your other question,there is indeed continuity in $x= 0$ (not precisely in $(0,0)$ since $f$ is a one-variable function). It doesn't matter if the gradient takes a sharp change in a certain point, the function may still be continuous (you can think of it as a sharp corner in its graph).

Comment: It is not always a sharp corner in a graph. For instance, the function:

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}0 & x=0 \\ x\sin\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right) & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

This function is continuous, but the derivative is undefined at $x=0$.

Answer (score 0):

A derivative is only defined at a point if it has the same value when approached from both sides in the real axis. When you have multiple derivatives at a certain point, then we say it is not differentiable at that point.